# Hashing parts of file using sed

Tags: unix, hash, sed, command

I am creating a script to hash some parts of the text. The point is, I would like to do it using sed. Here is how example string looks like:

`..HASHSTART.......HASHSTART..HASHEND..HASHEND..HASHSTART.....
.....HASHEND....HASHSTART.........`

I have three problems with it:

1. I would like to match "HASHSTART" and "HASHEND" properly. So for example if i will find first HASHSTART, then i would like to hash everything to first find of HASHEND, even if there is more HASHSTARTs between.
2. I would like to hash it even if there is a new line between HASHSTART and HASHEND.
3. If there is HASHSTART at the end and no HASHEND till end of the file, I would like to hash everything after.

By "hash" I mean here to change from . to @.

So with this input the output should be:

`..HASHSTART@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@HASHEND..HASHEND..HASHSTART@@@@@
@@@@@HASHEND....HASHSTART@@@@@@@@@`

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I have tried something like this:  sed 's/(HASHSTART)(.*)(HASHEND)/\1@\3/'  .
But the problem is to give many @ and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 awk -F 'HASHSTART' -vw=3 '{i=index($w,"HASHEND");if(i)print substr($w,1,i-1)}' file
```

-vw=3 postion (2,)

Comment: Actually I am not sure if this is working properly. Are you able to do similar version in sed? I would prefer to use sed than awk. Anyway, thanks for help.